# How can I change Blender's theme?

Tags: customization, theme

I just downloaded blender and its very bright. I want it darker. How can I change the color of it?

Comment: If you run into any trouble, see - [How can I get back to Blender's default theme?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1547/12)

Comment: Blender? Bright? What do you think of Microsoft Word?

Comment: The energy theme might be interesting for you: http://studiollb.wordpress.com/download/

Comment: @WChargin blinding

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you want to change is the *theme*.
Here is how its done. Open your user preferences <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>.<sup>1</sup> Then one the top you will see a couple of tabs one of the labelled *Themes* Then one the left from the drop down you can select a different theme. If you want a darker theme try *Elysium*.

[image]

[image]

[image]

And this is what it looks like.

[image]

If you want more themes you can get them here:
https://www.blendswap.com/blends/category/22

<sup>1</sup>: <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> on Mac. Edit menu -> Preferences in newer versions.

Comment: Why are there only like 5 different themes

Comment: @BlenderBoy you can install new ones by clicking *Install theme*

Comment: I think you have a typo in you shortcut to open the `User Preferences`

Answer (score 5):

You can customize the color of pretty much everything in *File > User preferences > [Themes](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Preferences/Themes)* (you can also open the *User preferences* by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>)

From the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Preferences/Themes):

> The colors for each editor can be set separately—simply select the editor you wish to change in the multi-choice list at the left, and
>   adjust colors as required. Notice that changes appear in real-time on
>   your screen. In addition, details such as the dot size in the 3D View
>   or the Graph Editor can also be changed.
>
> Themes use blenders preset system, you can save a theme to an XML and install it on another system.

You may want to try using some of the presets that come with blender, or some user made ones.

## Using presets

You can select a preset in *User preferences > Themes > Presets*:

[image]

You can install new theme presets stored in the `XML` format by pressing *Install theme* on the header and navigating to the `XML` preset file:

[image]

Some themes not included in blender yet are [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/blenderpython/code/HEAD/tree/scripts_library/scripts/presets/interface_theme/).

You can also create and delete your own presets by pressing the <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd>
buttons next to the *Presets* menu.

`XML` Preset files are stored in `/$blender_directory/$blender_version/scripts/presets/interface_theme/`
For more information on where `$blender_directory` might be see the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Introduction/Installing_Blender/DirectoryLayout):

> Blender can be installed system wide or run from an extracted bundled
>   with all necessary files contained.
>
> There are 3 different directories blender may use, their exact
>   locations are operating system dependent.

Note that there are some *Contrib* theme presets (see [this thread](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?241510-Updated-Interface-Theme-Presets!) for a list) that only come with SVN builds and are not included in the releases. You can get them from the `interface_theme` directory of a development build, or [directly from the SVN repo](https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-extensions/contrib/py/scripts/addons/presets/interface_theme/). With the latter method you might get a security warning, see the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Tools/SVN_checkout_and_usage):

> You will probably see an error message about the certificate that is
>   not issued by a trusted authority. However the certificate is fully
>   functional and will ensure secure transit of the data. You can
>   permanently accept this certificate.