# Change UI color

Tags: interface, theme

Currently, we can change any colors from the **Theme** settings. For example, if one likes the following, they can change to it.

[image]

How can I change C codes to set this **theme** as default for Blender?

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/save-custom-layout-in-blender-2-67b. You don't need to change the source code of Blender just to change the themes / settings / materials / etc, it's all included in startup file and it's enough to save it. If you went too far with themes, [return back to default theme](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1547/how-can-i-get-back-to-blenders-default-theme).

Comment: no no ... i want to change them from source code @MrZak .... i know that

Comment: Only to make that theme as default one ? I.e. you mean you don't want neither to press buttons in UI nor executing Python code from console to do that ? I guess you'll need to search then somewhere like http://developer.blender.org

Comment: when you build & compile blender first time, software load with a default theme and colors ..... i want change this @MrZak